# Uncapped vs SetInterval framerate for HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Looking at [this HTML5 game tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/) and it uses the following code to update the frame at 30 frames per second:

```
var FPS = 30;
setInterval(function() {
    update();
    draw();
}, 1000/FPS);
```

From the viewpoint of traditional videogames, it is bad practice to cap a game's framerate (and it's really annoying when games, usually bad console ports, do this). I am wondering if this is a necessity for an HTML5 canvas game. Would an unlimited framerate do something really bad like lock up the browser or use up all the computer's resources?

I am thinking of code something like this:

```
update();
function update()
{
    // Move stuff around
    draw();
}
function draw()
{
    // Draw the changes
    update();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It would for sure just _waste_ resources, because the display will not be updated that often, so a lot of the calculations/moves/whatever you make will just have no effect at all. Rendering engines of today’s browsers are _not_ “traditional videogame” engines, so don’t even try to make them into such. Look into `requestAnimationFrame` if you want to get the best of what’s possible today.

Comment: What do you mean that it is a bad practice to cap a game's frame rate? Have you ever developed a traditional video game? Do you know that irrespective of your game's frame rate most monitors always update at 60 FPS? Even if your game uses a higher frame rate your monitor will still only display 60 FPS. Using a fixed frame rate has several advantages: 1) The programmer needn't worry about a varying frame rate. All calculations are done relative to a fixed frame rate. 2) Variable frame rates suffer from problems like unrelated processes hogging up CPU time which are out of a programmer's control

Comment: @CBroe I was not aware that browsers didn't update at unlimited speeds. What is this speed that they update at, and is there a way to update when the browser updates?

Comment: @AaditMShah Some monitors have refresh rates above 60 FPS. Most games developed natively for PCs do not cap framerates, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check out window.requestAnimationFrame (RAF).**

As its name implies, RAF has been created to do a decent job of managing animations.

RAF tries to give you the best of capped and uncapped timers.

- RAF creates an animation loop that synchronizes well with the display refreshes.
- RAF waits asynchronously so your UI thread is not blocked while waiting for the next frame.
- RAF will automatically attempt to loop at about 60fps.
- Latest RAF gives you an elapsed timer that you can use to (1) skip this loop if you need fewer fps (2) catch-up your animation if the last frame was skipped--for example due to system garbage collection.